# What's the difference between TypedArray.getInteger() and TypedArray.getInt()?

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-xml, typed-arrays

Looking at the source code for TypedArray ([link](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/res/TypedArray.java)), I cannot seem to figure out what the difference between these two methods is. `getInt()` is basically the same as `getInteger()`, but with a small addition at the end that I don't understand. Can someone explain it to me?

The reason I need to know the difference is I am implementing a custom Preference subclass, and to get the default value I need to override `onGetDefaultValue()`, which grabs an integer from a TypedArray. Example:

```
@Override
protected Object onGetDefaultValue(TypedArray a, int index)
{
    return a.getInteger(index, DEFAULT_VALUE);
}
```

Here I'm using `getInteger()`, but if `getInt()` is better, then I will use that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They simply have different "all else fails" cases. They both return an `int` for a valid `int` and `defValue` for `null`. The difference is how they handle the case of neither of those.

From the [link](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/content/res/TypedArray.java):

```java
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

TypedValue v = mValue;
if (getValueAt(index, v)) {
    Log.w(Resources.TAG, "Converting to int: " + v);
    return XmlUtils.convertValueToInt(
        v.coerceToString(), defValue);
}
Log.w(Resources.TAG, "getInt of bad type: 0x"
      + Integer.toHexString(type));
return defValue;
```

This is the extra you are referring to. It appears to be converting an unknown value to a string then to an integer. This could be useful if you had `"12"` or some equivalent value stored.

Additionally `getInteger` throws an exception if it is not `null` and not an `int`. In contrast if all else fails `getInt` returns the default value.

Also note that the behavior of them in this odd case is different enough that calling one superior to the other in every case would be incorrect. The best solution is the one that matches your expectations for failure.

Comment: Thanks. So which one would you use for `onGetDefaultValue()`? I think I will go with `getInt()` because it "tries a bit harder" and will at least return something.

Comment: Hmmm, I just tested both with non-int non-null input (specified a gibberish string for the `android:defaultValue` XML attribute) and it looks like they both throw exceptions if an unknown value is encountered (`getInt()` throws an exception if the XMLUtils line fails). So I don't think it really matters which is used in `onGetDefaultValue()`...